# How Do I get A Script To Open Itself?

Tags: vbscript

I have created a VBScript file, and I want it to open itself again. I currently have

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("W:\\Downloads\\FileName.vbs")
```

But I want it to open itself *without* a specific path, because I don't know where the file will be. Is that possible?

Comment: `Wscript.ScriptFullName`

Comment: You mean put the script in ScriptFullName

Comment: `Wscript.ScriptFullName` [Returns the full path of the currently running script](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc5ywscw(v=vs.84).aspx),

Comment: Thank You, that fixed the problem

Comment: @notevenslightlyapcgod — Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 4):

As [@JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) pointed out: use the [`ScriptFullName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc5ywscw%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property to get the full path of the script.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run WScript.ScriptFullName
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one

```
CreateObject ("WScript.Shell").Run(".\filename.vbs")
```

It will open the file which is in the same folder in which the VBS file is , no need to specify the rest of the path.
You can add a MsgBox "text" so that the program does not terminates or else only one program will run oneat a time.

Comment: This still requires that you know part of the path (the file name). [This solution from May last year](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388477/19068) doesn't have that drawback.